# Как работает _getch() со "стрелочками" на клавиатуре?

Tags: c++, символы

Если использовать с `_getch()` любые буквы, то он вернёт значение этой буквы, таким образом можно проверить факт нажатия, однако если нажать "стрелочку", то он выдаст 2 значения - 225 и 40, 47, 48, 49 в зависимости от стрелочки. Если преобразовать в `char`, то мы получим pK, pH, pM... при том, что `_getch()` вернёт их по очереди при 2 разных вызовах, даже если при втором вызове ничего не нажималось.

---

Как сделать так, чтобы `_getch()` возвращал значение стрелочки одним символом? Или можно заменить эту функцию другой?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463201/getch-and-arrow-codes

Comment: Никак. Смотреть, что вернулось первым символом, и в зависимости от этого, если нужно, читать еще раз.

Comment: Первым символом возвращается одно и тоже, а следующие при следующем вызове.
Сейчас мне пришла идея вызывать сразу 2 раза гетч и читать только значение второго.